# How to change carrier on iPad 2nd generation?

Tags: ipad, cellular-data, cellular-carriers

I have a 2nd generation iPad which has both WiFi and Cellular connection. It is an iPad that I was using during a few years that I was living in Japan and has a Japanese phone company cellular connection.

Even when the iPad was reset, this specific connection would show up in settings. How can I set up the iPad to use in United States, with a US cellular connection?

Answer (score 2):

If you check the Apple Sim page for iPad here ([Use Apple SIM with Wi-Fi + Cellular models of iPad](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT203099)), it says that you can use a nano-SIM card in the SIM tray to set up a cellular data plan with a different carrier.

> **Japan**:
>
> - AU, DoCoMo, Softbank (purchased in a carrier retail location): The    embedded Apple SIM and nano-SIM tray are locked to the carrier that
>     sold you your iPad. Outside Japan, you can use the embedded Apple SIM 
>     or a nano-SIM card in the SIM tray to set up a cellular data plan
>     with a different carrier if you are outside Japan..
> - KDDI (KDDI retail locations): The embedded Apple SIM is locked to    KDDI in Japan. The nano-SIM tray is locked to the carrier that sold
>     you your iPad. Outside Japan, you can use the embedded Apple SIM or a 
>     nano-SIM card in the SIM tray to set up a cellular data plan with a
>     different carrier.

Comment: Thanks. I saw this also but wasn't clear on the wording regarding the SIM but I understand now that nano-SIM is basically the removable SIM in the older iPad versions.